# How would I find this volume integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

$\iiint_V\,(x^2 + y^2)\, \mathrm{d}V$

where V is the volume consisting of the points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ and $|z| \leq 1 - (x^2 + y^2)^2$

What would I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\iiint_V\,(x^2 + y^2)\, \mathrm{d}V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1+r^4}^{1-r^4}r^3\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

Comment: In a previous comment I forgot one is integrating $(x^2+y^2)=r^2,$ so that with the cylindrical volume element the integrand is indeed $r^3$ as you have it. And +1.

Comment: @ coffeemath Please. So thanks for your comment.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Would I need to integrate from the inner integrals outwards, i.e. evaluate the innermost limits with dz, then the second limits with dr and so on? Thanks very much for the answer as well

Comment: @Samuel Opiyo $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1+r^4}^{1-r^4}r^3\,dz\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}r^3(2-2r^4)drd\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac24-\frac 28\right)d\theta=\frac 14\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} $

Comment: Ohh I see I see, thanks @BehrouzMaleki!